# Ubuntu 20.04 Join Windows Domain for Samba Shares

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, domain

I've been trying to get an Ubuntu 20.04 server VM (Hyper-V) to join a Windows domain for the purpose of acting as a file server for Windows users, authenticating access to each directory for Windows domain users via the AD.

I have a Windows 2019 server configured as a domain controller and verified that Windows 10 clients can join the domain, users can logon and authenticate.

I have watched probably 15+ different YouTube videos and read 10+ web pages all claiming to show how to do it, but sadly my Ubuntu 20.04 always fails to find the domain controller when running realm.

I have re-installed Ubuntu five times already in order to start with clean machines but never found a working recipe to make it work.

Is there an official step by step guide that "works" from a clean ISO install that is actually verified to work?  I'm concerned that some/most/all of the other tutorials are assuming some things that I'm missing.

Comment: Check your DNS server settings.

Comment: They've each been changed to what ever each tutorial said. In fact, the Windows 2019 server was set as the only DNS server just to prove it was being used and I can ping everywhere else 'but' the Domain controller by name, and yes I've tried all variations of the name, with and without .local, upper case, lower case etc.   Tearing my hair out here.

Comment: I should add that since the above question I successfully did all this on Debian 10 first time.  All our production Linux servers are Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 so I was hoping to keep things the same.  I just need to figure out what I'm missing on Ubuntu that worked fine on Debian :(